# How do I add a new line w/ text in a PHP file?

Tags: php, ubuntu

OS: Ubuntu/Xfce, 14.04.

I have tried a bunch of solutions, but none of them worked for me. I know that "/n", PHP_EOL, or "/n/r" should add a new line. A form script from another file is suppose to add whatever was typed into a new line. It won't go into a new line, just the first line.

Here is my code:

```
$fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. "/HDdeltin/LoginSignup/Users/$con", "wb");
fwrite($fp,$text);
$writeemail = $email . "\n";
fwrite($fp,$writeemail);
fclose($fp);
```

What is wrong with the code? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure `$text` and `$email` are defined? Because this code works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've read your question right, you want to add a new line to the file and not overwrite it. My question would be, why are you still using PHP4 functions? Use PHP5 functions, since they're better, easier to use and more comfortable. Use this:

```
file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. "/HDdeltin/LoginSignup/Users/$con", "\n".$email, FILE_APPEND);
```

If you're already on a new line (because you already append a new line to your string before you've written it to your file), move "\n" to the other side of $email.

Comment: Hey, it works! Thanks! It won't let me mark the check mark for 2 minutes, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by using

```
$writeemail = $email . PHP_EOL;
```

or

```
$writeemail = $email . '</br>';
```

Comment: Still doesn't add it in a new line, just the first line. Thanks though. Do you know of anything else I can try?

Comment: did you try by $email . '</br>';

Answer (score 0):

Try adding something like

```
 "<br/>".PHP_EOL.
```

br is the html line break tag.

PHP_EOL actually adds a newline in the source code which is not displayed by html rendering angines.

Comment: do I type it in like    $writeemail = $email"<br/>" . PHP_EOL;    ?

Comment: You do know you have to use the UNIX or Windows new line tag and not the HTML one?

Comment: yes. but concatenate with a dot: $writemail = $email."<br/>".PHP_EOL;

Comment: @Charlotte: right, but shouldn't PHP_EOL take care of that?

Comment: @StephanRichter Yes, but what is the use of "<br />" in a file? It does nothing, it's just a string, for the filesystem it's just like "blabla". You have to use <br /> if you want a new line in your html code, but not in a file.

Comment: right, but it looked like user287210 wanted to generate an html email, in which case this might have been helpful.